# What is the intended difference between the timeout and execution_timeout arguments for BaseSensorOperator?

Tags: airflow

Version 1.10.6 documentation for [BaseSensorOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.6/_api/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator/index.html) states `timeout (int) – Time, in seconds before the task times out and fails`.

BaseSensorOperator inherits from [BaseOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.6/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator), the documentation states `execution_timeout (datetime.timedelta) – max time allowed for the execution of this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail.`

I do not understand what function `timeout` is providing over `execution_timeout`.

I've looked at the code for how each is used. They appear to affectively be doing the same thing, though I think there is an unintentional difference in behavior. I filed a JIRA for that [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues/AIRFLOW-5849). It may be intentional and just not documented.

Presumably, there is a reason for the `timeout` argument that I cannot find in the documentation, otherwise it would not exist. Maybe it's just not documented well?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood the `BaseSensorOperator` implements `execute` and uses this to run your `poke` implementation according the the `poke_interval`. This implementation of `execute` makes use of the `timeout` attribute to determine how long the execution has been running - incase your `poke` is running, but never evaluates to `True`.

The `execution_timeout` of the `BaseOperator` is a bit more mysterious to me and I couldn't pin it down to any concrete usages. However, as a thought experiment, consider the scenario where you implement a sensor and something in your `poke` implementation takes an age or perhaps can never complete. For example:

```
def poke(...):
    while True:
        print("Wasting your time...")
```

Because of this loop within each poke, the individual poke length is infinite. Thus, you will never actually check against your `timeout`, because it's only one call of `poke`. With this in mind, I would guess that the `execution_timeout` is there to catch problems like this and pull the plug. I would love to confirm is definitively though.

Comment: execution_timeout is used [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4132f3bc70d04c21fcb138d3eeeaf60b8e90011f/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L923-L930). I think that would interrupt the long running poke in your example. But my question is why is it a different parameter at all? Why not use `execution_timeout.total_seconds()` instead of `timeout` in `execute`

Comment: To be honest, I don't see a compelling reason to do it this way either. It could be a design choice to enable a subtle difference in behaviour between the two cases. Or it could be a design oversight, where two concepts that do the same thing have inadvertently been implemented!